# How to convert date format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in variable to dd-mm-yyyy in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, variables, formatting

I have jquery variable which stores the date value in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. I want to convert it into dd-mm-yyyy format to display on screen.

Comment: have a look at a library like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b3xLe6ps/1/

Comment: Did you try _anything_ at all?

Comment: Yes, i tried splitting the date and rearranging in the required format. But i just want to know is there any other efficient way of doing this like date_format like function??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using momentjs.
Read [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myDateFormatter (dateObject) {
        var d = new Date(dateObject);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

        return date;
    }; 


window.onload =function()
{
alert(myDateFormatter("2015-04-29 11:22:00"));
  
};
```

you can try below function

```
function myDateFormatter (dateObject) {
            var d = new Date(dateObject);
            var day = d.getDate();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            if (day < 10) {
                day = "0" + day;
            }
            if (month < 10) {
                month = "0" + month;
            }
            var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

            return date;
        };
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way like simple built in function where we just have to pass the format and get the value?

Comment: in such a case you can build your own function using switch case on the passed format...

Comment: there are few libraries available, you can use it but internally they use identical code to convert...